# AWS lambda extensions not sharing environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The following is a `secrets-wrapper.py` lambda extension:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3
import json
import os

LAMBDA_WRAPPER_NAME = "secrets-wrapper"


def debug_print(message):
    print(message, flush=True)


def error_print(message):
    print(message, flush=True)


def load_secrets():

    if not 'APP_PARAMS_PATH' in os.environ:
        error_print(
            f"{LAMBDA_WRAPPER_NAME} unable to load secrets APP_PARAMS_PATH not found")
        return

    app_config_path = os.environ['APP_PARAMS_PATH']
    if 'APP_ENV' in os.environ:
        env = os.environ['APP_ENV']
        full_config_path = '/' + env + '/' + app_config_path
    else:
        full_config_path = '/' + app_config_path

    debug_print(
        f"{LAMBDA_WRAPPER_NAME} Loading secrets for path {full_config_path}")

    try:
        client = boto3.client('ssm')
        # Get all parameters for this app
        param_details = client.get_parameters_by_path(
            Path=full_config_path,
            Recursive=False,
            WithDecryption=True
        )

        # Loop through the returned parameters and populate the ConfigParser
        if 'Parameters' in param_details:
            for param in param_details.get('Parameters'):
                debug_print(f"Found param: {param}")
                param_name = param.get('Name').split("/")[-1]
                debug_print(f"Name: {param_name}")
                param_value = param.get('Value')
                debug_print(f"Value: {param_value}")
                os.environ[param_name] = param_value
    except:
        debug_print(f"{LAMBDA_WRAPPER_NAME} could not load from SSM")
        raise Exception(f"{LAMBDA_WRAPPER_NAME} could not load from SSM")


def main():
    load_secrets()

    # Start the function
    args = os.sys.argv[1:]
    os.system(" ".join(args))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and this is the function:

```
import json
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print(f"ENV foo check: {`os.environ.get('foo')`}", flush=True)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

when setting the `APP_ENV` to the lambda function:

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name my-function-example \
    --environment "Variables={APP_NAME=myApp}"
```

within the lambda-extension it fetches no problem:

```
env = os.environ['APP_ENV'] #dev
```

However, when setting the environment variables within the extension                 `os.environ[param_name] = param_value`

when fetching it back in the invoked function `os.environ.get('foo')`
it is returned as `None` as if it was not set. If I output the set environment variable anywhere in the extension it will be indeed set.

Question is:

1. is the environment variable strictly one direction?
2. if not, how can I share ENV variables from extension to runtime function?

Comment: You have to show full code, as the two lines that you provided are out of context and are correct.

Comment: @Marcin full code given

Comment: I was sure that your problem is due to the execution of the lambda in a different process, but I was wrong:

When executing `os.system(" ".join(args))` you open a subshell that runs the lambda: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system
Environment variables should be shared with subshell, and here is a simple example to prove it:
```
import os

os.environ["aaa"] = "5"
os.system('python -c "import os; print(os.environ[\'aaa\'])"')
```

Are you sure that `"foo"` is a key inside your SSM? Can you add a print after the `os.environ` of the inserted key?

Comment: One of the output experiment i've tried was: read from SM, output from SM, write to temp file, and write to ENV. then read it back.
Within the main function, I would output the entire stack of ENV: any new variables from SM was not present. Any old ENV that was suppose to get overwritten by SM was READ during extension but within main function reverted back